# Python counting with str and int

Tags: python

Everyone, hello!

I'm not able to count properly, and I'm at a loss. A second pair of eyes would really be helpful.

I'm getting a variable from my config file as:

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
count1 = config.get('Counter','count1')
>>> print count1
5
```

However, when I want to simply substract - 1 from this variable, as so:

```
count1 = (count1 - 1)
```

I'm confronted with an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are obviously trying to do a substraction of a `str` and an `int`, as the error message tells you. Since `1` is an `int`, then `count1` must be a `str`. You can `print type(count1)` before the line that gives you the error to make sure of that. Then, just convert it with `int()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do arithmetic with strings, you have to convert it first to an integer with the `int` function:

```
count1 = int(config.get('Counter', 'count1'))
```

You could also use the `config.getint` or `config.getfloat` methods.

If you need a float, you can use the `float` function instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> count1 = config.get('Counter','count1')
```

Above will simply return a string type. And, that's why you are getting the error because you can't subtract an int from a string type.

If you need `int` from config, you can use [`RawConfigParser.getint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.getint) method:

```
>>> count1 = config.getint('Counter','count1')
```